# jQuery: using variable ID duplicates function output

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, dynamic, contenteditable

I would like to use an onclick event in order to show a div inside a box and add some buttons allowing users to edit its content.

When I trigger the same function with a separate button it all works fine but when I try to add a class (editable) to all divs on my page to trigger the event by clicking on the divs it duplicates my buttons. 
So instead of two buttons above and below the box it then shows four buttons for each.

I hope anyone here can help me with this.

My code (simplified, styles removed):

**The HTML (example with only one div):**

```
<form id="editorForm" action="" method="post">
    <div id="demo" class="editable">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis ac neque mollis, iaculis lacus ut, imperdiet orci. Phasellus vulputate purus quis dictum scelerisque. Curabitur fermentum leo odio, in iaculis risus adipiscing quis.
    </div>               
</form>
```

**The JS:**

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function(e)
    {       
        $('.editable').on('click', function(event)
        {
            editID = event.target.id;
            var innerID = 'innerID' + editID;
            var txt = $('#'+editID).html(); 
            var btnTop = "<div id='editor'> \
                <div id='editTop'> \
                <button type='button' onclick='function1()'>Button 1</button> \
                <button type='button' onclick='function2()'>Button 2</button> \
                </div> \
                <div id='editInput'>";
            var btnBottom = "</div> \
                <div id='editBottom'> \
                <button type='button' onclick='editCancel()'>Cancel</button> \
                <button type='button' onclick='editSave()'>Save</button> \
                </div> \
                </div>";

            $('#'+editID).html(btnTop + txt + btnBottom);
            $('#editInput').attr('contenteditable', 'true');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Many thanks for any help with this, Tim.

Comment: why not use event.target instead of it's id for direct targeting with jQuery? `var target = event.target; var txt = $( target ).txt();` ?

Comment: Unless you're repeating the div id somewhere, it seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/GFmgG/

Comment: Or you can just ignore the id totally: http://jsfiddle.net/GFmgG/1/

Comment: thanks to everyone for the fast replies; using event.target creates the buttons correct BUT i then have the issue that when you click inside the editable div afterwards it then adds the buttons again within the div so in the end it still duplicates them, just in different steps now.

Comment: to explain: what i would like to achieve here is that by click on every div with the class "editable" it puts this div's content into a box and add two buttons above and below this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, make sure your div ids are unique (as any other element in the page), and try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.editable').on('click', function() {
        // If it's already an editable one, just ignore it
        if ($(this).find('div[contenteditable=true]').length > 0) {
            return false;
        }

        // Wrap the div content (text) into an editable one
        $(this).wrapInner('<div contenteditable="true" />');

        // Top buttons
        var btnTopWrapper = $('<div />');
        var btnTop1 = $('<button />').text('Button 1').on('click', function() {
            function1();
        });
        var btnTop2 = $('<button />').text('Button 2').on('click', function() {
            function2();
        });
        $(btnTopWrapper).append(btnTop1).append(btnTop2);

        // Bottom buttons
        var btnBottomWrapper = $('<div />');
        var btnBottom1 = $('<button />').text('Cancel').on('click', function () {
            editCancel();
        });
        var btnBottom2 = $('<button />').text('Save').on('click', function () {
            editSave();
        });
        $(btnBottomWrapper).append(btnBottom1).append(btnBottom2);

        // Stick the top buttons before the editable div
        $(this).prepend(btnTopWrapper);

        // Stick the bottom buttons after the editable div
        $(this).append(btnBottomWrapper);
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GFmgG/2/

Comment: This works perfect - thanks a lot for the fast reply and helpful comments !